# how to create different tables from a single topic in KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have a Kafka topic which has customer, purchase, product etc data. I want to create different streams from this single topic.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried so far and any errors you see

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume the message(in JSON format) of your Kafka topic like:

```
{
    "customer_id":value,
    "customer_name":value,
    "purchase_id":value,
    "purchase_desc":value,
    "product_id":value,
    "product_name":value
}
```

And assume the topic name is `my_topic`.

So you can do like this:

For `customer` STREAM:

```
CREATE STREAM customer (
    -- which 'customer_id' match the JSON key
    customer_id BIGINT,
    customer_name VARCHAR
) WITH (
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON',
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'my_topic'
);
```

For `purchase` table:

```
CREATE STREAM purchase (
    purchase_id BIGINT,
    purchase_desc VARCHAR
) WITH (
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON',
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'my_topic'
);
```

For `product` table:

```
CREATE STREAM product (
    product_id BIGINT,
    product_name VARCHAR
) WITH (
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON',
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'my_topic'
);
```